# Should highlighted quotes in an article be aligned with the body text?

Tags: typography, text, page-layout, alignment, composition

I am wondering whether quotes need to be included in text positioning.

See example below:

[image]

Is this correct?
Or should the quotes be disregarded when positioning the text?

**What's the best way to align a highlighted quote in an article, in relation to the positioning of the body text?**

Comment: It is an actual quote (citation) in the example above, and it is the only one on the page.

Comment: I'm not sure if your edit is correct, because in the example above its not really a heading, just big text.

Comment: Yep I think its better then my version, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, I'd use [hanging punctuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging_punctuation).

Essentially you ignore the quotes and align to text. The punctuation (quote mark) hangs outside the column edge. This is very common in typesetting and dates back to the Gutenberg bible.

Overall hanging punctuation helps the alignment of text appear more solid or uniform.

Comment: Each layout is different. Most of the time, if the quote is used as above, I'd hang the punctuation. Only when a quote is relatively the same size and part of body text would I consider indenting and adding space above/below the quote.

Comment: It's really a localized design choice. But if I have a quote with left-aligned or justified text, I hang the punctuation.